# (IOS)addSubview generate Crash

Tags: ios

I am using `xib` and `Autolayouts` to create a view. I am trying to import and instantiate the view in the `ViewController`. App is getting crashed when i am assigning the view to `tableHeaderView`.

But when I have created the view object directly and assigned it to `tableHeaderView`, the app is working fine.

The crash is only when using `xib` for creation of view.

**crash log :**

```
malloc: stack logs deleted from /tmp/stack logs.1816.1cae000.lolbox.u9cU7G.index
```

**create view code:**

```
 BOXToolPlayersInfoTableHeaderView * tableHeaderView  = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                loadNibNamed:@"BOXToolPlayersInfoTableHeaderView"
                                                                owner:self options:nil]firstObject];

_customTableViewHeader = tableHeaderView;
```

using `xib` , I ensure `_customTableViewHeader` not `nil`:

```
if ([self.customTableViewHeader respondsToSelector:@selector(playerDetail)]) {

        [((BOXToolPlayersInfoTableHeaderView *)_customTableViewHeader) setPlayerDetail:mainFollower];


        if (!_customTableViewHeader.superview) {

           _tableView.tableHeaderView = _customTableViewHeader; // crash location
        }
        [_customTableViewHeader setNeedsLayout];
    }
```

Comment: @chinnari , Thank you help me to modify and check.

Comment: I am delete all constraint in the xib , app is working fine. I think I found the cause of the crash.